# ¿Qué significa "." en "from . import views"?

Tags: python

Cuando usas el siguiente comando:

```
from . import views
```

¿Qué significa el `.` después de `from`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El punto se usa cuando usas un `import` [relativo](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references). Es decir, un `import` donde lo que importas está en la misma carpeta en la que está el fichero *.py* donde usas ese import. Si usases `..` indica que está en una carpeta 'anterior' o padre, como cuando estás en linux y usas el directorio actual o un directorio padre.

Por ejemplo, imagina un paquete que tenga la estructura siguiente:

```
paquete
 |_____ __init__.py
 |_____ fichero1.py
 |_____ fichero2.py
```

En ese caso, desde `fichero1` podrías llamar a funcionalidad que está en `fichero2` usando:

`from . import fichero2`

Answer (score 1):

Si entiendo bien la pregunta quieres saber qué significa el punto en la expresión de importación del módulo.

Cuando se tiene varios paquetes con un módulo que tiene el mismo nombre, se puede importar usando el punto (`.`) para indicar que se busquen los módulos respectivos con el mismo nombre.

```
from paquete1 import modulox
from paquete2 import modulox
```

Si el módulo X reside en varios paquetes se puede simplificar la importación así:

```
from . import modulox
```

Comment: Puedes revisar la sección 6.4.2 de esta página https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html para mayor claridad.